# Dell Power Edge Server / Ubuntu 16.04 certification schedule

Tags: upgrade

We have a Dell Power Edge T430 with PowerEdge RAID controller (PERC) H730 configured with RAID-1 running Ubuntu 14.04 (certified).

PCI compliance is calling for Apache2 >= 2.4.14.  Using "apt-cache policy apache2" we see that we can only get to 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13 without upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.  It is a LAMP stack and we would prefer not going the custom repo route.

When will this hardware be certified for Ubuntu 16.04?
https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/make/Dell/?query=&category=Desktop&category=Laptop&category=Server&release=16.04+LTS&level=Any

Since this is in a production environment, we are reluctant to initiate an upgrade to 16.04 without certification unless there is a proven path.

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: If it works fine with 14.04, I can't think of why it wouldn't work well with 16.04... but I can understand your hesitation, being that it's a production server :)

Comment: Also, I would strongly discourage upgrading. Rather, I would suggest a clean install. Many people have had problems with the upgrade breaking their LAMP stack (just judging from questions asked here), not to mention the people who've had their machines become unbootable after the update...